# What's the correct way to implement Tap To Focus for camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on an app which has a custom camera screen, for which I'm supposed to implement tap to focus, like in the Android(more specifically, the Galaxy S4) camera app.

I've tried using the steps outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#metering-focus-areas), but it doesn't seem to cause any noticeable focusing. The Focus Mode is set to Continuous Picture(we are supporting only a specific device).

When the user taps on the camera preview, I need to be focusing on the top half of the image. For this, I use the code snippet

```
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

if (parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() > 0) {

    ArrayList<Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>(1);
    focusAreas.add(new Area(new Rect(-1000, -1000, 1000, 0), 750));

    parameters.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

I do NOT want AutoFocus as it takes too long to focus on the image. I am interested only in the top half of the image. Has anybody successfully implemented Tap to Focus along with Continuous Picture mode?

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Android really needs a much better camera API.

Comment: Agree about camera API. Had good progress with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647 Take a look. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 27):

Bumped into this issue recently. As MatheusJardimB said, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647)  helps a lot.

However, in my case, I wanted to start in the `ContinuousPicture` mode then be able to tap to focus and then continue with the `ContinuousPicture` mode.

I managed to get it to work by using the `onAutoFocus` method of the `Camera.AutoFocusCallback()`. I'm not sure if it's the best or the prettiest way of doing it, but it seems to work.

Here's the code:

```
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Camera camera = mCamera.getCamera();
                camera.cancelAutoFocus();
                Rect focusRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1f);

                Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);

                if (parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() > 0) {
                    List<Area> mylist = new ArrayList<Area>();
                    mylist.add(new Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000));
                    parameters.setFocusAreas(mylist);
                }

                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
                        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                        if (!params.getFocusMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            camera.setParameters(params);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

You could just change the focus area to

```
ArrayList<Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>(1);
focusAreas.add(new Area(new Rect(-1000, -1000, 1000, 0), 750));
```

and it should work.

**UPDATE**

I recently acquired a Samsung S5 and tested this out on it. It didn't work that well, so I added a few modifications and it's working now. This was also successfully tested on the Galaxy S6 and Galaxy Note4.

Here's the modified code:

```
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera camera = mCamera.getCamera();
            camera.cancelAutoFocus();
            Rect focusRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1f);

            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            if (parameters.getFocusMode().equals(
                    Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO) {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            }

            if (parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() > 0) {
                List<Area> mylist = new ArrayList<Area>();
                mylist.add(new Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000));
                parameters.setFocusAreas(mylist);
            }

            try {
                camera.cancelAutoFocus();
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        if (!camera.getParameters().getFocusMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            if (parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() > 0) {
                                parameters.setFocusAreas(null);
                            }
                            camera.setParameters(parameters);
                            camera.startPreview();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea how we are suppose to support multiple devices when every device acts differently?

Comment: Good question, I wish I had the answer... I guess I'd say test on as many devices as possible...

Comment: calculateTapArea() is undefined. please explain

Comment: @bcorso there are a few libraries around, like the ones by Commonsware, that at least provide a bit of work towards device specific issues. The only way to be sure is the old fashioned "test on everything you can" though.

Comment: @QadirHussain `calculateTapArea()` is just a method that converts the touch position x:y to a rectangle with coordinates between -1000:-1000 and 1000:1000([as defined in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusAreas%28%29))

Comment: if (parameters.getFocusMode().equals(
                    Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO) {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            }
If its already in Auto mode why are we setting it again?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO you are right, there was a typo in that part, a "!" is missing. If you check the edits you'll see that someone actually added it while trying to make the answer clearer.

Answer (score 23):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18460647/3014036) has the solution. I just added the implementation of some missing methods in his code.

```
private static  final int FOCUS_AREA_SIZE= 300;
```

//

```
mCameraPreview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                focusOnTouch(event);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

//

```
 private void focusOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mCamera != null ) {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        if (parameters.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0){
            Log.i(TAG,"fancy !");
            Rect rect = calculateFocusArea(event.getX(), event.getY());

            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            List<Camera.Area> meteringAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
            meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(rect, 800));
            parameters.setFocusAreas(meteringAreas);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusTakePictureCallback);
        }else {
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusTakePictureCallback);
        }
    }
}

private Rect calculateFocusArea(float x, float y) {
    int left = clamp(Float.valueOf((x / mCameraPreview.getWidth()) * 2000 - 1000).intValue(), FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);
    int top = clamp(Float.valueOf((y / mCameraPreview.getHeight()) * 2000 - 1000).intValue(), FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);

    return new Rect(left, top, left + FOCUS_AREA_SIZE, top + FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);
}

private int clamp(int touchCoordinateInCameraReper, int focusAreaSize) {
    int result;
    if (Math.abs(touchCoordinateInCameraReper)+focusAreaSize/2>1000){
        if (touchCoordinateInCameraReper>0){
            result = 1000 - focusAreaSize/2;
        } else {
            result = -1000 + focusAreaSize/2;
        }
    } else{
         result = touchCoordinateInCameraReper - focusAreaSize/2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

// implement this callback to trigger the focus.

```
private Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusTakePictureCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            if (success) {
                // do something...
                Log.i("tap_to_focus","success!");
            } else {
                // do something...
                Log.i("tap_to_focus","fail!");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: mAutoFocusTakePictureCallback cannot be resolved to a variable, please explain

Comment: mAutoFocusTakePictureCallback is as its name indicates it, an instance of Camera.AutoFocusCallback. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not work. :( Where do you cancel auto focus?

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? neither the question or the answer is speaking about "canceling the auto focus"...?

Comment: I didn't try it. PS: I posted this answer more than two years ago, in an older project. So may be you need to make some changes to get it working with "camera2" . good luck.

Comment: Don't forget mCamera.startPreview(); after setting the focus, else it will get stuck after taking a photo.

Answer (score 2):

[One of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23754117/2422013) causes your camera to discard the focus points previously given and return to continuous focus which I don't think makes sense.

Also if you take a look at the link in the post the original answer uses         parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

I've implemented the above with this line of code instead of Continuous focus and it seems to work much better.

Comment: Please link to the answer.. the list changes dynamically.

Comment: Not sure how to do that @cybermonkey (new to stack overflow) but the answer I am referring to is by "Dude"

Comment: That's ok, I've submitted a suggested edit on your answer for you :-). You can either accept it now, or wait for the community to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 binding.cPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
        }
    });


 Camera.AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }};
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue.
I've checked this on many devices, and many Android versions.

It appears that **focus-area is not working in CONTINUOUS focus-mode**.

My workaround is to set focus-mode to AUTO or MACRO along with setting focus-area:

```
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Please note that the stock Camera app on Galaxy S3 & S4 works the same way: it's permanently in continuous mode. When you touch the screen it switches to auto & sets focus-area. But after a while it comes back to continuous mode, and focus-area goes back to the center of the screen.

I hope this helps you somehow.