# Why Instagram app for Android can have manual focus?

Tags: android, android-camera, instagram

The android camera class does not have any api to let third party app do manual focus (tap on area of the screen to get focus), but seem like Instagram app has the feature implemented. 
How they achieved it?

Comment: I wouldn't call tap-to-autofocus ["manual focus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_focus) by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Is [`setFocusAreas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusAreas%28java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.Camera.Area%3E%29) not what you're looking for?  [`getFocusAreas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusAreas%28%29) documents its usage.

See also:

- [Android setFocusArea and Auto Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647/android-setfocusarea-and-auto-focus)