# Xamarin.Android Camera Touch to Focus

Tags: xamarin, camera, focus

I am using Xamarin.Android to use inbuilt camera app to take a photo
but there are two missed things that I cant do and I have been googling them for long time:

1. I want to get a msg or popup (anything) after pressing the button to take a photo like "photo taken"
2. I want to let the user focus on any point of the camera - TAP TO FOCUS

```cs
async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    camera.StopPreview();
    Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
    parameters.FocusMode = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto;
    camera.SetParameters(parameters);
    var image = textureView.Bitmap;
    try
    {
        var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
        var folderPath = absolutePath + "/Camera";
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("photo_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 92, fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
        image.Recycle();
        var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
        intent.SetData(uri);
        MainActivity.Instance.SendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"               ", ex.Message);
    }
    camera.StartPreview();
}
```

I tried this but not working:

```cs
public void OnAutoFocus(bool success, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
{
    var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
    if (parameters.FocusMode != Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture)
    {
        parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;
        if (parameters.MaxNumFocusAreas > 0)
        {
            parameters.FocusAreas = null;
        }
        camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        camera.StartPreview();
    }
}
public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View view, MotionEvent e)
{
    if (camera != null)
    {
        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        camera.CancelAutoFocus();
        Rect focusRect = CalculateTapArea(e.GetX(), e.GetY(), 1f);
        if (parameters.FocusMode != Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto)
        {
            parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto;
        }
        if (parameters.MaxNumFocusAreas > 0)
        {
            List<Area> mylist = new List<Area>();
            mylist.Add(new Android.Hardware.Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000));
            parameters.FocusAreas = mylist;
        }
        try
        {
            camera.CancelAutoFocus();
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            camera.StartPreview();
            camera.AutoFocus(this);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private Rect CalculateTapArea(object x, object y, float coefficient)
{
    var focusAreaSize = 500;
    int areaSize = Java.Lang.Float.ValueOf(focusAreaSize * coefficient).IntValue();
    int left = clamp((int) x - areaSize / 2, 0, textureView.Width - areaSize);
    int top = clamp((int) y - areaSize / 2, 0, textureView.Height - areaSize);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, left + areaSize, top + areaSize);
    Matrix.MapRect(rectF);
    return new Rect((int) System.Math.Round(rectF.Left), (int) System.Math.Round(rectF.Top), (int) System.Math.Round(rectF.Right),
        (int) System.Math.Round(rectF.Bottom));
}
private int clamp(int x, int min, int max)
{
    if (x > max)
    {
        return max;
    }
    if (x < min)
    {
        return min;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: To notify the user (point 1) that the photo is taken you can use Toast, refer https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.Toast/ for more info.

Comment: thanks i will try it

Comment: Here is a discussion may be helpful for you .(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900263/tap-to-focus-for-camera-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

For focusing the camera when touching the preview you will need to:

1. Add a touch event handler to listen for the user touching the preview
2. Get the X and Y coordinates from that touch event, which are usually in the event arguments
3. Create a rectangle to focus to tell the Android Camera where to focus and in which area
4. Set `FocusAreas` and `MeteringAreas` on `Camera.Parameters` from your rectangle
5. Set the new `Camera.Parameters` on the camera
6. Set a `AutoFocus` callback on the camera
7. When the callback triggers, remove the callback from the camera, and cancel auto focus

To notify the user about a picture being taken, you can use a `Toast` or create a area in your preview where you want to show such messages. It is entirely up to you how you want to notify the user.

Comment: i have tried something but it didnt work and i am still fresh with xamarin

Comment: i cant add it here, i dont know how to post it

Comment: i added it as an answer , can you see it ?

Comment: You shouldn't add it as an answer, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: my camera is in a AXML file named CameraLayout.AXML
and camera appear in TextureView with ID textureView
and i have 2 button 1 for flash and 1 for take photo

Comment: i added it as a comment

Comment: you got it sir ?

Comment: i dont know , when i tab or touch the camera nothing happen and

Comment: camera.AutoFocus(this);
in this line i get issue

Comment: CheeseBaron any help ?